# How do i count characters in java including uppercase and lowercase?

Tags: java, char, java.util.scanner

The following is the code I'm using. The output file prints correctly but does not print the correct number of character or upper/lower case letters.

```
public class FileProcessing 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
    File file1 = new File("input.txt");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file1);
    scanner.hasNextLine();
    String s = scanner.nextLine();
    int length = s.length();
    char[] charAnalysis = s.toCharArray();
    int lowercase = 0;
    int uppercase = 0;
    for (char element : charAnalysis) 
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(element)) 
        {
            uppercase++;
        }
        else if (Character.isLowerCase(element)) 
        {
            lowercase++;
        }
    }
    File file2 = new File("output.txt");
        try (PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(file2)) 
        {
            ps.println("Number of characters is " + length);
            ps.println("Number of lower case letters is " + uppercase);
            ps.println("Number of upper case letters is " + lowercase);   
        }
        catch(IOException e) 
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmm, looks actually good to me, can you post the content of input.txt?

Comment: It might be helpful to show what is currently being "printed" and what is expected.

Comment: Maybe it's exactly what you want but you're reading only the first line of the input file.

Comment: If you're just concerned with the file, why are you taking input from user again?

Comment: @NicholasK he takes this line from file not from user

Comment: @RafałSokalski : Clearly there's something wrong with this code. I doubt `String s = scanner.nextLine();
    int length = s.length();` is supposed to get the entire length of the file

Comment: Not entire but first line only

Comment: @RafałSokalski : whats the point of that? clearly logic related issues in this code.

Comment: Probably just learning programming. I don't think it's going to be some big application.

Comment: But only @cmark can tell us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program correctly count uppercase and lowercase characters.
You made a mistake when you save output to your file:

You try to save uppercase as lower case.

```
ps.println("Number of **lower case** letters is " + **uppercase**);
ps.println("Number of **upper case** letters is " + **lowercase**);
```

The solution is to replace variables:

```
        ps.println("Number of lower case letters is " + lowercase);
        ps.println("Number of upper case letters is " + uppercase);
```

What is important you read only one line from file so your program will count characters in first line only.

If you want to count every line you need to read lines in loop and then count the characters.